# How do you revert to a professional colour chooser in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, colors

When I want to choose a colour for the desktop background or for the terminal's profile, for example, the program is like a program for kids. You can't choose the colours according to value, saturation, hue etc. with precision and fast, as with a professional colour chooser, like it was before. So, is there a way to change the kids-like colour chooser for a professional colour-chooser?

Answer (score 0):

Not that i know of, its how the GNOME devs wanted to do it. I admit I dont like it either, but I don't even use the GUI to change the colors like that, I use my terminal config settings.